# Add/Remove users in TFS 2015 using REST API powershell

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I want to add or remove users from TFS using REST API. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afraid this can't be achieved through Rest API for now. If you really want to do it programmatically. You can use client API.

You can try to use [`IIdentityManagementService.ReadIdentity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731745.aspx) along with [`IIdentityManagementService.AddMemberToApplicationGroup()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.client.iidentitymanagementservice.addmembertoapplicationgroup.aspx) to add Windows users to TFS groups, even if those Windows users are not known to TFS yet.

This is accomplished by specifying the [`ReadIdentityOptions.IncludeReadFromSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.common.readidentityoptions.aspx) option.

Below is an example of adding a Windows user `VSALM\Barry` to the `Fabrikam Fiber Web Team` (TFS Group), in the `FabrikamFiber` Team Project, in the `http://vsalm:8080/tfs/FabrikamFiberCollection` (Also applies to server level)

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://vsalm:8080/tfs/FabrikamFiberCollection"));

            var ims = tpc.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

            var tfsGroupIdentity = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName,
                                                    "[FabrikamFiber]\\Fabrikam Fiber Web Team",
                                                    MembershipQuery.None,
                                                    ReadIdentityOptions.IncludeReadFromSource);            

            var userIdentity = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName,
                                                    "VSALM\\Barry",
                                                    MembershipQuery.None,
                                                    ReadIdentityOptions.IncludeReadFromSource);

            ims.AddMemberToApplicationGroup(tfsGroupIdentity.Descriptor, userIdentity.Descriptor);
        }
    }
}
```